# In flutter, there is a difficulty with making a http.get() request

Tags: flutter, dart, http, get

I'm learning about Flutter's API and http requests, and I'm having a problem: they paste exactly into the string URL as get, but when I publish it as a string, it shows an error:

> argument type 'String' parameter type given to 'Uri' It isn't possible.

I hope this helps.
Below is my sample code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class requestAssistant{
  static Future<dynamic> getRequest(String url) async{
    // http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    try{
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        String jdata =  response.body;
        var decodeData = jsonDecode(jdata);
        return decodeData;
      }
      else{
        return "";
      }
    }
    catch(exp){
      return "";
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you use the Dio package for API calls. It provides the best solution for all HTTP request-related needs.

to fix your issue, you can convert your String URL to URI type like this :

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(url);
```

and then pass the converted URI